# Постоянное увеличение значения массива

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы, json

Суть такова. Есть json с набором значений такого вида

```
"anual":[
["2018-01-30","101.96"],
["2018-01-29","111.98"],
["2018-01-26","107.71"],
["2018-01-25","109.60"],
["2018-01-24","99.48"]
]
```

Мне нужно взять каждое первое значение ("2018-01-30) и заменить его на свое, допустим "0", дальше мне нужно в каждом объекте это значение увеличивать на три. В итоге должно получится так:

```
"anual":[
["0","101.96"],
["3","111.98"],
["6","107.71"],
["9","109.60"],
["12","99.48"]
]
```

На данный момент получилось заменить каждое первое значение в объекте, но увеличивать его не получается, вот код:

```
var anual = json.anual;

    $.each(anual,function(key,data) {
      $.each(data, function(index,value) {

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=2) {

            data[i] = 0;

            console.log(data);

        }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var json = {
  "anual": [
    ["2018-01-30", "101.96"],
    ["2018-01-29", "111.98"],
    ["2018-01-26", "107.71"],
    ["2018-01-25", "109.60"],
    ["2018-01-24", "99.48"]
  ]
}

var anual = json.anual;
anual.forEach(function(item, index) {
  item[0] = index * 3;
});

console.log(anual);
```

Почитать:

- [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 0):

По идее, алгоритм таков,

```
data[i]=i*3;
```

тогда для:
0-0
1-3
2-6
3-9
4-12
...

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так:

```js
var json = {
  "anual": [
    ["2018-01-30", "101.96"],
    ["2018-01-29", "111.98"],
    ["2018-01-26", "107.71"],
    ["2018-01-25", "109.60"],
    ["2018-01-24", "99.48"]
  ]
}

var anual = json.anual;
var value = 0; // начальное значение - ноль 
anual.forEach(function(element) { // пройдем по каждому элементу массива
  element[0] = value; // присвоим новое значение первому элементу (первый - нулевой)
  value += 3; // эквивалентно `value = value + 3;` то есть увеличим на 3
});

console.log(anual);
```

P.S. За основу взят ответ от [@AGS17](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/235242/ags17), но только у меня реализовано иначе.